# Problems creating odds ratios for a binary regression in R

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I am creating a binary logistic regression in R studio. So far I have performed the regression and I am trying to convert it to odds ratios using the function:

```
  install.packages(c("glm"))
regression<-glm(wellbeing.dummy ~ age[, "25-44"] + age[, "45-54"] + age[, "55-64"] +
                  age[, "65-74"] + age[,"75+"] + marstat[, "Single"] + 
                  marstat[, "Widowed"] + sex[, "Female"] + socioeco[, "Intermediate"] + socioeco[, "Manual"] +
                 socioeco[, "Other"] + workhrs[, "Part-Time"] + ons.data$MCZ_8
                  , family=binomial(link="logit"),
                weights=ons.data$INDWGTr, na.action=na.omit)
summary(regression)

####Producing odds ratios for the logistic regression####

install.packages(c("car"))
library('car')
vif(regression)
OR <- exp(coef(regression))
odds<-exp(cbind(OR=coef(regression), confint(regression)))
round(odds, 3)
```

It is when I get to the lines where I am trying to make the odds function (odds<-...) that I receive the error:

```
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in profile.glm(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace) : 
  profiling has found a better solution, so original fit had not converged
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

This is stopping the object 'odds' from being made, so the final line of code turns the error 'object 'odds' not found'.

Can anyone provide some help on how I can get around this, or an alternative way of making odds ratios for my regression? I'm very new to R so apologies if this is really obvious or if I'm just a bit slow.

Answer (score 3):

I'll first explain the warnings.

1. `In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!`

This occurs when you have non-integer sampling weights supplied to the `weights` argument. The warning is unimportant, but to prevent it from displaying you can use `family = quasibinomial()` instead. More on this below.

2. `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`

This means the model perfectly predicted some cases, which implies the model failed to converge to stable maximum likelihood estimates. You have perfect separation.

---

The error comes from `confint()`, which calls `profile()` on the regression object. Because the model failed to converge, `profile()` produces this error. You simply cannot fit the model as-is and you need to adjust it. There are many posts on this site dealing with perfect separation in logistic regression.

---

An additional complication is your survey weights. You cannot use the standard errors and confidence intervals produced by `glm()`. Instead, your uncertainty estimation needs to take into account the survey weights. The `svyglm()` function in the `survey` package does this correctly. It will still not help the model converge in the face of perfect separation; for that, you need other adjustments.

This is a fairly advanced statistical problem: perfect separation in a logistic regression with survey weights. I advise you consult with an applied statistician familiar with these topics to ensure your analysis is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the data, so I will make some of my own.

```
library(tidyverse)

n = 100
X = MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0, 10), Sigma = diag(10))
beta = rnorm(ncol(X))
eta = -0.8 + X %*% beta
p = plogis(eta)
y = rbinom(n, 1, p)

d = as_tibble(X) %>% 
    mutate(y=y)
```

Fitting the glm is straight forward.  As an aside, you should never dichotomize a continuous variable like age.  Nevertheless...`

```
fit = glm(y ~ ., data = d, family = binomial())
```

Using the `broom` package, we can extract the coefficients

```
tidied_fit = broom::tidy(fit)

   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)   -1.02      0.560    -1.82  0.0688  
 2 V1             2.48      0.942     2.63  0.00851 
 3 V2            -1.50      0.553    -2.72  0.00662 
 4 V3            -4.95      1.45     -3.42  0.000632
 5 V4             1.24      0.678     1.83  0.0667  
 6 V5             0.490     0.650     0.754 0.451   
 7 V6            -1.61      0.760    -2.11  0.0347  
 8 V7             2.03      0.608     3.34  0.000838
 9 V8             2.12      0.581     3.64  0.000271
10 V9            -1.47      0.661    -2.22  0.0264  
11 V10            1.48      0.638     2.33  0.0200
```

The `estimate` column is the log odds ratio.  In order to get odds ratios, simply exponentiate

```
tidied_fit %>% 
  mutate(OR = exp(estimate))

   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value       OR
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)   -1.02      0.560    -1.82  0.0688    0.361  
 2 V1             2.48      0.942     2.63  0.00851  11.9    
 3 V2            -1.50      0.553    -2.72  0.00662   0.222  
 4 V3            -4.95      1.45     -3.42  0.000632  0.00712
 5 V4             1.24      0.678     1.83  0.0667    3.47   
 6 V5             0.490     0.650     0.754 0.451     1.63   
 7 V6            -1.61      0.760    -2.11  0.0347    0.201  
 8 V7             2.03      0.608     3.34  0.000838  7.62   
 9 V8             2.12      0.581     3.64  0.000271  8.31   
10 V9            -1.47      0.661    -2.22  0.0264    0.231  
11 V10            1.48      0.638     2.33  0.0200    4.41
```

If the tidyverse is not your style, you can do this with base R using...

```
log_odds = coef(fit)
odds_ratios = exp(log_odds)
```

however, the intercept term has a different interpretation.  It is the odds of the outcome, not an odds ratio.